# How can the client receive "pong" from server if it has no forwarded ports

Tags: java, networking, port

It might be a weird question but my doubt is the following: If i need to manually forward a port to make my server listen to it, lets say port 123 so that a client can send information to it -using a random port- , lets say 321, how is the server able to respond back to that client in a way that the client receives the answer through that random port 321 if that port wasnt manually forwarded, unlike 123?

Comment: A router tracks the outgoing connection and will forward an incoming packet to the sending port when it sees a packet matching the signature.

Comment: @MikeW thank you, i understand now. If you make it an actual answer ill accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A router tracks the outgoing connection and will forward an incoming packet to the sending port when it sees a packet matching the signature.